# Is it possible to backup individual files with Deja Dup?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

In the Deja Dup preferences, it is possible to select certain folders to backup and certain folders to exclude.
 I would like to be able to backup individual files in my Home folder *(Such as `.vimrc` and `.bashrc`)*, but I don't see any way to do this.

So my question is, is it possible to either

- Select individual files *(instead of whole folders)* to backup, **or**
- backup my Home folder, but exclude all subfolders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to mterry last Febuary, this isn't something Deja Dup can currently do:

https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/99973

Although he's talking about exclusion, it's the same principle as inclusion. Your better off symlinking the files you want to backup into a separate directory and then backing up that.

Comment: May need to be the other way round. Maintain the original config files in a folder somewhere under the folder that you are backing up, and have a symlink in the original location. Or, as bmaupin indicated, with hardlinks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments on this answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/65868/18665

the only way to do it is to create hardlinks of the individual files you wish to be backed up in a folder that's backed up by Déjà Dup.