# How to backup a single file with deja-dup?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

when I reinstall I prefer to have a new system; however there are some configuration files in ~/ might like to keep.  Can I back up a single file with deja dup? (note these files may need to stay in ~/ to work)

Comment: I can't hold but to say `(gzip file-to-backup.extension && sudo chmod 000 file-to-backup.extension.gz && mv file-to-backup.extension.gz) &` (if you like using the terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (perhaps, let me know if it works) create a new directory called `~/.files-to-be-backed-up/` and then symlink your individual files into that directory:

```
mkdir ~/.files-to-be-backed-up/
ln -s ~/Desktop/file ~/.files-to-be-backed-up/file
```

And then just set Deja-Dup to backup anything in that hidden directory.

Comment: That won't work, as Deja Dup will back up the symlinks themselves.  You'd need to use hardlinks (i.e. use the same commands you gave, but without the -s).

Comment: @MichaelTerry Are you sure symlinks don't work? I would swear I've had them working in the past.

Comment: If you specify a symlink as an explicit folder to back up or ignore, they will be followed and it will work as you expect.  But if there are symlinks somewhere inside folders you mention, they will not be followed.